# XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/create' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, api

I am using react as front-end and sending request from `localhost:3000/contact` to my API that is in laravel `http://localhost:8000/create`
I am seeing this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/create' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. main.1eda3b0ea85babe00767.hot-update.js:183
> AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code:
> 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

I have tried using proxy but then the error is 404 and request url becomes: `localhost:3000/create`
I double checked the proxy that was:
"proxy":"http://localhost:8000"

Code in Contact.jsx is:

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/create', data)
```

and in laravel:

```php
Route::post('/create', [crudController::class, 'store']);
```

Controller code:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // var_dump("asdf").die();
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required',
        
    ]);
    //var_dump($validator).die();

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 400);
    }

    $project = new form();
    
    $project->name = $request->input('name');
    $project->email = $request->input('email');
    $project->message = $request->input('message');
    
    //var_dump($project).die();
    if ($project->save()) {
        return response()->json(['Data inserted successfully' => true, 'data' => $project], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unable to create project'], 500);
    }
}
```

I have tested it with POSTMAN and it is working fine with that.

Comment: different port number signifies different origin - need to add suitable headers to your PHP script, ie: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')` for example

Comment: The solution to this is to have your PHP application respond to requests with the correct headers which indicate to the browser that requests to that application from the localhost:3000 domain are acceptable. You can read more about it here: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cross-origin-request-headerscors-with-php-headers) including the concepts, how it works and what you need to do to enable cross-origin requests in your application. It's a common issue, so it's worth learning about it in detail.

Comment: `I have tested it with POSTMAN and it is working fine with that`...because a request from Postman (or any other non-browser, non-ajax client) isn't considered to be a cross-origin AJAX request, so it isn't subject to CORS restrictions. Again, read the links above to learn more.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I got it resolved by modifiying my existing code to this code:
fetch('http://localhost:8000/create', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })

and in API:
Log::info($request->json()->all());
TO see if i was receiving the data from my form to api

Comment: @RehmanAli if you answer your original question, you can mark it as resolved